# Marshaling gives error "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt"

Tags: c#, c, marshalling, dllimport

I need to use **C** library for working with NetCDF file format in my **C#** project. To receive some portion of informtaion from **NetCDF** file, i need to use methods **nc_open** to open CDF file, **nc_inq_att** to get the length of array (this one works fine and gives no error) and then **nc_get_att_text** to get pointer to array of chars. Then I need to get this array of chars and transform them into string.

Original documentation on UniData web-site describes **nc_get_att_text**:

```
int nc_get_att_text 
(   
int ncid,
int varid,
const char* name,
char* value 
)
```

**Parameters**
**ncid**    NetCDF file or group ID.
**varid**   Variable ID, or NC_GLOBAL for a global attribute.
**name**    Attribute name.
**value**   Pointer that will get array of attribute value(s).

I use code like this to import **netcdf.dll**:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace test
{
    private class LoadData
    {
        private LoadData()
        { 
            OpenFileDialog File = new OpenFileDialog();
            int ncid;
            int errorid;
            string op_name;

            File.Filter = "File .cdf|*.cdf";
            if (File.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                //Open CDF file - this one works fine
                errorid = nc_open(File.FileName, CreateMode.NC_NOWRITE, out ncid);

                //inquiring the length of array - this one works fine and gives me correct value (checked with original NetCDF software). attlength.ToInt64() gives result 7.
                errorid = nc_inq_att(ncid, -1, "operator_name", out NcType atttype, out IntPtr attlength);

                //getting pointer works fine
                errorid = nc_get_att_text(ncid, -1, "operator_name", out IntPtr value);

                //sending pointer to array of char and array length to my method
                op_name = CharPointerToString(value, attlength.ToInt64());
            }
        }

        // This method should copy bytes to my bytes array and then make a string from them.
        private string CharPointerToString(IntPtr _pointer, long _length)
        {
            string result;
            char[] chars = new char[(int)_length];
            IntPtr pointer = _pointer;
            Marshal.Copy(_pointer, chars, 0, (int)_length); // here I get Violation "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt"
            return result = new string(chars);
        }

        [DllImport("netcdf.dll")]
        public static extern int nc_open(string _FileName, CreateMode _CreateMode, out int ncid);

        [DllImport("netcdf.dll")]
        public static extern int nc_inq_att(int _ncid, int _varid, string _AttributeName, out NcType _type, out IntPtr _AttributeLength);

        [DllImport("netcdf.dll")]
        public static extern int nc_get_att_text(int _ncid, int _varid, string _AttributeName, out IntPtr _value);
    }
}
```

Currently I have no idea, how to handle this and what causes the problem.

I have found that in **C** char can by only one byte due to ASCII encoding, whether char in **C#** is 4 bytes. I have replaced code in my function with this one to ready bytes instead of chars and to transform bytes to string using ASCII encoding, but this gave the same error.

```
 private string CharPointerToString(IntPtr _pointer, long _length)
    {
       string result;
       byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)_length];
       Marshal.Copy(_pointer, bytes, 0, (int)_length);
       result = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
       return result;
    }
```

Original library is build for **x64** systems, I also build my project to **x64**. I also tried to build for **Any CPU**, no difference.

Answer (score 0):

It appears (from doing a bit of research) that there was an erroneous assumption that nc_get_att_text() handles memory for you, allocating the space for the result on its own.

To the best of my knowledge, this is not the case. I am not speaking to the rest of the implementation, but from the [documentation](https://docs.unidata.ucar.edu/netcdf-c/current/group__attributes.html#ga83c961529fa27b1768528e5d27cc3eb4) it seems that you are meant to allocate a buffer, and then YOU pass the pointer to that function, rather than it passing one to you.

To implement this solution, you change your P/Invoke definition to accept rather than emit the pointer:

```
[DllImport("netcdf.dll")]
public static extern int nc_get_att_text(int _ncid, int _varid, string _AttributeName, IntPtr _value);
```

And then allocate the memory, before passing it in:

```
IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(attLength + 1);// One more byte to hold trailing null
try
{
    int errorid = nc_get_att_text(ncid, -1, "operator_name", buffer);
    string op_name = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(buffer, attLength);
}
finally
{
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);
}
```

Comment: The only moment lays in char definition in C and C#. I was right, they are different. Need to read bytes from buffer and then transform them into string using  result = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);